# TFS Checkin Policy to ensure that code do not contain specific word or snippet

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I am a .net developer.In my c# code sometimes for debugging I use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() method to attach the process for debugging with Visual Studio. And I do remove or comment this method call before check-in the code since it is only for my debugging purpose. However I am thinking is there a way to detect if I have missed this step and accidentally checking the code with this method call.

I am using TFS 2008 and Visual Studio 2008. Is it possible to perform such check before check-in?

Comment: Why is necessary for you use this line of code to debbug? You software is web?

Comment: Its not a web but the process is not started by user by double click. Instead some other application invokes it.

Comment: Have you found a solution? thx